# WebFlux on Tomcat, manage to many parallel request incoming to a controller

Tags: linux, spring, sockets, spring-webflux

I have a controller that just return a Mono and I send it a number of parallel request in order to see the limits and I see that the OS where Tomcat run it just do not accept any more socket connection (based on max file handling set up in this case in MacOs) and from the client where I send this multiple requests I get `Connection has been closed before response` . This is fine, but how can I possibly set in Spring this max number of file handling in order to manage this circumstance? Like if OS set file handling limit at 200 I would like Spring to understand this and do something before the OS blocks all.

My client basically is:

```
for(int i= 0; i< 100000; i++){
  webClient.get.uri("http//example/controller") . . .subscribe()
}
```

Comment: `Flux.range(0, numberOfRequests).flatMap(i -> webClient.get().uri("http://example...").retrieve().bodyToMono(MyResponse.class), maxWantedConcurrency).subscribe(response -> System.out.println("Received a response: "+response, error -> System.err.println("request pipeline failed: "+error.getMessage()), () -> System.out.println("pipeline completed"));`

Comment: @amanin. thanks, can you explain pls?

Comment: You are doing it by client, what I mean is in Spring server controller to do it, so before too many files in OS

Comment: I think you misunderstand how reactive streams work. For one, your initial example forces all requests to be triggered in parallel without any back-pressure handling. My first comment only transform the loop to a flux, to make it more reactive. The number of maximum requests in parallel is then controlled by the `maxWantedConcurrency` parameter of the `flatMap` operator. It should lower the burden upon HTTP connections, because it prevents all requests to compete for resources, by limiting the number of parallel requests.